# move one file from /a/b/c/d.txt to /x/a/b/c/d.txt , Create full tree if not exist

Tags: shell, file-management

I am traversing through directories and moving old files to a different location.
For eg. a file located in path `/a/b/c/d.txt` I want to move to `/x/a/b/c/d.txt` without errors.
Is it possible in a single command? If `mv` doesn't work , then combination of `cp` and `rm` will work?

- Only need to move single file at a time.
- If dest tree exists already then it should not raise an error.
- If dest tree doesn't exist then, create.

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97131/is-there-a-parents-option-for-mv-like-for-cp) doesnt seem to address the requirement. Also I am able to get this done in multiple lines of code. So could there be predefined one-liner kind of option? (Want to integrate this with a programming language)

Comment: @muru I could not make it work. Tried with the answers. And it looks like we need to create a wrapper function as a workaround. I was looking for something predefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly not what you are looking for, if you need to use standard commands only, but `rsync` may help:

```
$ mkdir a a/b a/b/c; echo foo >a/b/c/d.txt; tree a
a
└── b
    └── c
        └── d.txt

2 directories, 1 file
```

```
$ rsync --relative --remove-source-files a/b/c/d.txt x/
```

```
$ tree a x
a
└── b
    └── c
x
└── a
    └── b
        └── c
            └── d.txt

5 directories, 1 file
```

From the [manual](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1):

> `--relative, -R`
>
> Use relative paths. This means that the full path names specified on the command line are sent to the server rather than just the last parts of the filenames. ...

and

> `--remove-source-files`
>
> This tells rsync to remove from the sending side the files (meaning non-directories) that are a part of the transfer and have been successfully duplicated on the receiving side.

Comment: Wow..! exactly what i needed . `--relative` creates subdirectories. `--remove-source-files` deletes source file . So if `--remove-source-files` is omitted then it works as copy. Am I right?

Comment: @sjd Yes, that's what `rsync` does by default. It has lots of options (to handle different kinds of files, preserve attributes, etc.), I only included the essential ones.