# "mkdir" command inside the "cp" or "mv" command

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

How can I create a new directory while copying or moving a file or directory using cp or mv command respectively?

Suppose my destination folder is not defined and I want to create the destination while I am writing the copy or move command.

Thank for your support.

Comment: Related: [Is there a --parents option for mv like for cp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97131/is-there-a-parents-option-for-mv-like-for-cp)

Comment: Could you show some example of what you mean? Do you mean something that creates a `dest` directory in the command `mv /some/file dest`?

Comment: How would you form the name of the destination directory to be created ? Would it be a fixed name or a name that would depend on context, for instance on other filenames being moved, on parent directory's name, ... ?

Comment: yet another: [Linux: copy and create destination dir if it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529946/linux-copy-and-create-destination-dir-if-it-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to copy or move a file into a new (to be created) directory or directories, as in

```
cp file new-dir/sub-dir/new-file-name
```

there is no option to do that just with `cp` or `mv`.

You can create the directories with `mkdir -p`:

```
mkdir -p new-dir/sub-dir/ && cp file new-dir/sub-dir/new-file-name
```

To copy, you could also use the less commonly used `install` command, which has a `-D` option to do just that:

> ```
> -D     create all leading components of DEST except the last,
>        or all components of --target-directory, then copy SOURCE to DEST
> ```

```
install -D file new-dir/sub-dir/new-file-name
```

Also see the answers to [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529946/linux-copy-and-create-destination-dir-if-it-does-not-exist).